# Descending Order When A is smaller than B the list must be in ascending order, can u help me to set descending for B < A

Tags: python

```
import random

A = random.randint(1, 30)
print('A =', A)

B = random.randint(1, 30)
print('B=', B)

v = list(range(A, B))

if (A < B):
    print(v)
else:
    ???
```

When A is smaller than B the list must be in ascending order, can u help me to set when B will be smaller than A for the list to go in descending order PLS!!!

Comment: `range(A, B)` will create empty list then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random

A = random.randint(1, 30)
print('A =', A)

B = random.randint(1, 30)
print('B=', B)

v = list(range(min(A, B), max(A, B) + 1))

if (A < B):
    print(v)
else:
    print(sorted(v, reverse=True))
```

Answer (score 1):

use `reversed()` function:

```
list(reversed(range(A,B)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood what you want you can do this (you can take the range from A to B in a descending order):

```
else:
    v = list(range(A,B,-1)
```